# How to call the Win32 GetCurrentDirectory function from C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, com-interop

The prototype of `GetCurrentDirectory`

```
DWORD GetCurrentDirectory(
  [in]  DWORD  nBufferLength,
  [out] LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

`DWORD` is `unsigned long`, `LPTSTR` is a pointer to wchar buffer in Unicode environment. It can be called from C++

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 256

int main() {
  TCHAR buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
  GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to encapsulate this win32 function in C#, but failed.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint GetCurrentDirectory(uint nBufferLength, out StringBuilder lpBuffer);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory

Comment: Read the documentation: [Default Marshaling for Strings: Fixed Length String Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings#fixed-length-string-buffers). It provides an example for `GetWindowText()`, which has the same kind of parameters as `GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, this is really helpful for setting an example how to call win32 from c#.

Comment: instead of fighting with Interoperabilty, which can be a pain in somewhere as you are noticing, look for what is already available in .Net,  i.e `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
For such a basic task and many other not so basic, you will find something in the framework much easier to work with compared to interoperability

Comment: The answer is simple: Don't. Don't use `GetCurrentDirectory`. Ever. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) even *explicitly* tells you not to: *"Multithreaded applications and shared library code should not use the `GetCurrentDirectory` function"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to remove `out` on the `StringBuilder` parameter:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint GetCurrentDirectory(uint nBufferLength, StringBuilder lpBuffer);
```

And then pre-allocate the buffer when calling the function:

```
const int MAX_PATH = 260;
var buffer = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
var len = GetCurrentDirectory(buffer.Capacity, buffer);
var path = buffer.ToString(0, len);
```

That being said, you can just use [`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory) instead:

```
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```